# Issue with connecting to magento connector in mule

Tags: magento, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to configure a magento connector into my anypoint studio.
I have a magento instance running locally and I have created a user and role for the SOAP requests.

On adding the magento connector to the flow, I try to test the connection using the following properties

Url: http://localhost/magento/api/v2_soap
magento user name and password which is the api key.

However when I test the connection, I get an error
org.mule.api.ConnectionException:(301) Moved Permanently

I also tried giving the url http://localhost/magento/index.php/ap...
However it gives the same error.
Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: `301` is not an error, errors are in the `4xx` and `5xx` ranges: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

Username and API key will allows you to connect using Magento connector

EX: https://sashistore.gostorego.com + /api/v2_soap?wsdl is url

For Reference Please go through : http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Let me know if it works